# Coffescript '@' or this in functions and classes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Have the following class in coffeescript:

```
class Canvas
  constructor: (finder) ->
    @canvas = $(finder)
    @mouse_down()
  mouse_down: ->
    @canvas.mousedown (e) ->
      mouse_x = e.pageX - @offsetLeft
      ### ... ###
      @redraw()
  redraw: ->
    ### ... ###
```

The problem is to call class object `redraw` method in `mousedown` function. What's the best solution to do it? I found only:

```
  mouse_down: ->
    @canvas.mousedown (e) =>
      mouse_x = e.pageX - @canvas[0].offsetLeft
      ### ... ###
      @redraw()
```

Comment: Congratulations -- you have found the solution! The [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) `=>` binds the function to `@` (or `this`).

Comment: @LinusGThiel, is it the only solution? It doesn't look pretty.

Comment: There's always [Tim Toady](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), but that's exactly the use-case for `=>`. What, in particular, don't you like about it?

Comment: @LinusGThiel, @canvas[0].offsetLeft instead of this.offsetLeft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
class Canvas
   constructor: (finder) ->
      @canvas = $(finder)
      @mouse_down()
   mouse_down: ->
      redrawCallback = @redraw
      @canvas.mousedown (e) ->
         mouse_x = e.pageX - @offsetLeft
         ### ... ###
         redrawCallback()
   redraw: ->
      ### ... ###
```

If redraw refers anyhow to @ (Canvas class) do it better like this (it's safer anyway):

```
class Canvas
  constructor: (finder) ->
     @canvas = $(finder)
     @mouse_down()
  mouse_down: ->
     redrawCallback = => @redraw()
     @canvas.mousedown (e) ->
        mouse_x = e.pageX - @offsetLeft
        ### ... ###
        redrawCallback()
  redraw: ->
     ### ... ###
```

PS. Although it's a matter of taste, I believe camel case would match better for method names than underscoring.

Answer (score 1):

You found a better solution. But if you want you can write this:

```
mouse_down: ->
    self = @ 
    @canvas.mousedown (e) ->
      mouse_x = e.pageX - self.canvas[0].offsetLeft
      ### ... ###
      self.redraw()
```

Comment: @tiktak right, I understand your point. Yeah, here you could use `@offsetLeft`.